# Strange behaviour of OracleDataReader in Read() method

Tags: c#, oracle

Hi all Oracle experts,

I have a rather strange behaviour of a very very simple program only intended to test basic data acquisition from a remote Oracle database with C#.

I have created a simple C# program as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST={{Server}})(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME={{DataSource}})));User Id={{Username}};Password={{Password}};";

    connectionString = connectionString.Replace("{{DataSource}}", "Actual service name");
    connectionString = connectionString.Replace("{{Server}}", "Actual Server IP");
    connectionString = connectionString.Replace("{{Username}}", "Actual username");
    connectionString = connectionString.Replace("{{Password}}", "Actual password");

    using (connection = new OracleConnection {ConnectionString = connectionString})
    {
      connection.Open();
      using ( var cmd = connection.CreateCommand() )
      {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The table I am reading from has 220.000 entries, and the problem with the code is, that after an amount of "rows" the reader.Read() just stops. It is supposed to return "false" if there are no more records, and there are still records to come, but the Read() function is called and never returns. Even after letting it try for hours it does not come back.

Does anyone have had a similar experience?

I already heard not to use the Microsoft Oracle Data Driver, so I am using the one from oracle. But still the problem does not go away.

The amount of rows retrieved changes if you change the SQL Command, but also not in a very understandable way: I thought if this has to do with the network buffers I can reduce the columns to get more rows, but it works in the opposite direction. More columns result in more rows.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Having you ut chunking your data retrieval, i.e. only returning *n* number of records per query, processing those then getting the next chunk?

Comment: Hi slugster, 
already thought about that, but the problem is - depending on the SQL text - the number of records returned before blocking is different. Select * delivers 9135 of 221000, Select ID delivers only 25 !!! records before blocking.